# Location of Command Prompt Commands

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

Where are the commands located for Command Prompt? I know this is possible in Linux, but what about windows?

I want to rename certain commands so I can make my own using the original name.

Im doing this on a 32bit Windows XP if that helps.

More specifically, where can I find the tree command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/312926/windows-equivalent-of-which-command-in-linux

in windows 7 there's the where command.

You can overwrite the standard commands, but this will break a lot of stuff.
You would also have to modify your path environment variable

in windows 7 tree is located in C:\Windows\System32\tree.com

This might be a useful site for you
http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: Thanks, I found it in XP at C:\WINDOWS\system32\tree.com

Answer (score 0):

Use a bat file of the same name to override an inbuilt external command. Some commands are internal so you have to specify .bat. Also if calling the overridden program specify the extension.

Comment: I also wanted to rename commands so they would still exist. Its all good now, C:\WINDOWS\system32\tree.com for example is where the tree command lays.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of commands in Windows command prompt. The *internal* commands are built-in inside the command processor program, that is called `cmd.exe`. You may inspect such commands if you open cmd.exe file with an Hex editor, or even directly with Notepad (although doing that requires a lot of patience!); to know the location of cmd.exe file, type: `set comspec`. Examples of internal commands are DIR, COPY, TYPE, MD, etc. (the simplest ones) and all Batch-file commands, like GOTO, IF, FOR, REM, etc. There is no way to change the name of an internal command, unless you modify the cmd.exe file (for example, using the same Hex editor) that, although *possible*, is **NEVER** recommended!!!

The *external* commands reside in disk files with .com or .exe extension that are grouped in certain subdirectories, usually in C:\Windows\System or C:\Windows\System32; these subdirectories must appear in %PATH% variable in order to execute the external commands directly in the command prompt. You may locate the folder where an executable file resides using the following command, that review folders included in PATH variable only (you can not use wild-cards in this case):

```
for %a in (tree.com tree.exe) do @echo/%~$PATH:a
```

You may directly change the name of any command-name.exe file; however, this practice is not recommended. A simpler option is create a Batch file with the same name of a standard command (and .bat extension) and place it in a folder that will be included in PATH variable *before* the standard commands folder (or in the current directory). For example, create a file named `tree.bat` and place it in `C:\Users\MyName\MyCommands`; then, modify PATH variable this way: `path=C:\Users\MyName\MyCommands;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32`. If you need to use the standard `tree` command inside your `tree.bat` file, just include the proper extension: `tree.com`.